# Cold Draft from Kitchen Exhaust Vent

Tags: insulation, kitchens

my gas bill has been really high this winter so I have made it a mission to air seal my home as much as practical. I keep my home pretty warm at 72-73F since I have an infant who can't sleep with blankets yet. My 2 story home was built in 2002 and is located in Northern California.

I've already done some attic air sealing, but still have a lot more work to do. But, recently I made a major discovery. The downstairs kitchen seems to be one of the colder areas. I have a gas cooktop and exhaust above it. I was searching for the source of cold air and opened the cabinet which hides the vent to find it was frigid in that cabinet. As far as I can tell the 7inch rigid exhaust vent has no damper, which allows outside air to pour directly in the kitchen. I am thinking of installing a vertical damper I found on Amazon "Butterfly Backdraft Damper (7 Inch) (BD 7)". Once the outside air is stopped/slowed from directly entering the house, I would want to insulate the metal vent pipe.

- Would this violate any code? Is the un-damped vent needed to allow fresh air for my gas appliances. I have the gas cooktop, gas oven next to it, and gas fireplace around 40ft away in a connected living room.
- Is adding a damper discouraged? I have read they can get grease buildup and eventually get stuck closed. I cook bacon/fatty meat on my cooktop on a daily basis.
- Is wrapping the vent pipe with insulation a code violation/bad idea? I would look for something fire rated, maybe a wrap designed for chimneys? I haven't scoured the internet yet, but it looks like they have wraps to make a vent fireproof (which don't list an R value). Maybe they have HVAC wraps that are rated to contact hot ducts which provide some R value? The hot air contains smoke, so maybe I need something completely fire resistant? My other option is to build an air sealed box around the vent pipe using foam board, but not sure how fire resistant those boards are either.

Thanks for the help!
[image: Vent Exhaust]
[image: Vent Wall]

Comment: There should be two vents in that area.  One the exhaust vent which what you want to do should be okay.  You should also have an intake/make up air vent to let fresh air in for the gas burners.  Most intake vents should have 90 degree elbow pointing down outside the wall, cold air does not rise, it sinks.

Comment: So by looking at the side of my house, I can tell there is only the one vent. And yes, it does have a downward facing vent, but still enough cold is seeping through.

Maybe inlet vents were required later on than 2002, when houses started becoming more air tight?

Comment: They started in the early 80s with air tight and needing heat/energy recovery systems for fresh air.  Some fuel burning devices also use their own intakes, but maybe back then did not.  As long as the dampers open with the exhaust fan on you should be good with the exhaust.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up ordering this damper from FAMCO.
https://www.famcomfg.com/product/butterfly-backdraft-damper/

I'll see how cold that cabinet gets one I "seal" the vent, and if needed figure out insulating it next.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but a possible path: how about cranking down your thermostat to a much cheaper 67/68 and adding an electric space heater to wherever the infant sleeps? Unless you are somewhere with very high electric rates this will probably be cheaper.